# React-Native, Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an application with React-Native, and I'm trying to retrieve data from a Firebase collection and display items on JournalScreen.js. I understand the error, but I'm completely stumped as to where it is in the code. Can someone possibly have a look and shed some light on this problem for me, I would be very grateful!

**JournalScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, View, Text, FlatList, Image} from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../components/Firebase';
import colours from '../components/Colours';
import dimensions from '../components/ScreenSize';
import {  MaterialIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default class JournalScreen extends React.Component {
  state={
    fontLoaded:false,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('entries').orderBy("date");
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      isRefreshing: true,
      DATA:null
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'montserrat-regular': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      'montserrat-light': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
      'montserrat-semibold': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
      'montserrat-bold': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
      'MontserratBold': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
      'MontserratSemibold': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
      'MontserratRegular': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      'MontserratLight': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded:true});
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const entries = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { date, mood, image, details} = doc.data();
      entries.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc,
        date,
        mood,
        image,
        details,
      });
    });
    console.log('Update',entries.length)
    this.setState({
      DATA:entries,
      isRefreshing: false,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log(error, info.componentStack)
  }

  render() {
    const item = ({item}) => (
      <View style="" key={item.key}>
        {
          item.image &&
          <Image
          source={{ url: item.image }}
          style = {styles.cardImage}
          />
        }
        <View style = {styles.cardHeader}>
          <Text style = {styles.mood}>
            {item.mood}
          </Text>
          <Text style = {styles.date}>
            {item.date.toDate().toDateString()}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.copy}>
            { item.details }
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.editContainer}>
          <MaterialIcons.Button name = "edit"
            backgroundColor = "#bb1d68"
            size = {20}
            style = {styles.btn}
            onPress={() => navigate('NoteDetailScreen',{key: item.key})}>
            Edit
      </MaterialIcons.Button>

        </View>

      </View>
    )

    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
      if(this.state.DATA != null){
      return(
        <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
          {
            this.state.DATA.length == 0 &&
            <Text style = {{padding: 10, color: 'white', marginTop: 40}}>Sorry, you haven't made an entry yet!</Text>
          }

                <FlatList
              data={this.state.DATA}
              renderItem={item}
              keyExtractor={item.id}
              refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>

        )
      } else {
        return (
          <View
          style = {{ flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <ActivityIndicator size ='large'/>
          </View>

        );
      }
  }
}
```

**Error log**

```
[Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.]
    in RCTView (at JournalScreen.js:73)
    in RCTView (at VirtualizedList.js:1925)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:767)
    in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:1038)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1178)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1183)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:676)
    in FlatList (at JournalScreen.js:115)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:55)
    in SafeAreaView (at JournalScreen.js:109)
    in JournalScreen
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:38)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:44)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:27)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:117)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:131)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:101)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:100)
    in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:26)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:99)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:41)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at App.js:16)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:286)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:39)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:38)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:15)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in RootErrorBoundary
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: Where does line 73 point to, which view?

Comment: @Konstantin It's this view
`<View style="" key={item.key}>`

Comment: Really hard to tell as I don't see your data, I would recommend commenting out the parts of the code in your `const item` to isolate the error and then see why it's occurring

Comment: Just followed your advice, and it appears that the error is being caused by the following line: `item.image &&` @Konstantin

Comment: try to use ( ) to coat your Image

Comment: @Konstantin It ended up being an issue with my image selector function, thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Glad you've found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was caused by a error with my imagePicker function, where it was storing the path incorrectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
const item = props => {
    const {key, image, mood, date, details} = props;
    return (
        <View style="" key={key}>
            {image != null ?
                <Image
                    source={{ uri:image }}
                    style = {styles.cardImage}
                /> : ''
            }
            <View style = {styles.cardHeader}>
                <Text style = {styles.mood}>
                    {mood}
                </Text>
                <Text style = {styles.date}>
                    {date.toDate().toDateString()}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.copy}>
                    {details }
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.editContainer}>
                <MaterialIcons.Button name = "edit"
                                      backgroundColor = "#bb1d68"
                                      size = {20}
                                      style = {styles.btn}
                                      onPress={() => navigate('NoteDetailScreen',{key:key})}>
                    Edit
                </MaterialIcons.Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```